# Horizontal menu break when resolution is changed

Tags: html, css, browser

I have a horizontal menu which is work fine. By the time resolution is changed and actually become smaller to 1024*768 the menu break to second line which is kind of messy. Any idea how to keep it at one line or do something appropriate technically?
P.S: i don't want to use JQuery. I use my own codes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: `<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a" title="Home Page" id="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="b" title="About us" id="About_us">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>`

Comment: CSS: `#menu{ background:#A1DBE6;}
#menu ul { margin:0; padding:7px; list-style:none; border-top:2px solid #6C939A; }
#menu ul li { margin:0; padding:0; display: inline;}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-width` property for the menu id. This will restrict your div not to slide down after a certain limit is reached.

For instance:

```
#menu{ background:#A1DBE6; min-width:xx; /* You can replace your value in pixels instead of xx */}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i got the point and my solution. However, another problem just showed up. I defined everything relatively with percent, and when i set min-width, in low resolution everything change but menu, and it's not fine, because a horizontal scroll appear showing menu out of layout. what do you suggest me in this case?

Comment: provide a JSfiddle code (dont paste here like u did earlier) to know your actual issue. - @Kaveh

Comment: Now add min-width to #menu and look what happens!